# passbook update a pass

Tags: iphone, ios6, passbook

[image]

[image]

you can see the two pic, at the top_right of first pic is "add"

and  at the top_right of second pic is "update". i can do the effect as first pic.but i don't know how to do the second effect, how to use "update " instead of the "add".

Comment: What do you mean by "do the effect"? The option for update comes when a pass with the same serial number and deviceTypeIdentifier has already been installed and there are difference in the passes content. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @thomasmcguinness - I think you meant to say `passTypeIdentifier` not deviceTypeIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add or update is controlled by the `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` in the pass.json.

If a user's passbook does not contain a pass of `passTypeIdentifier` pass.com.example with `serialNumber` 1234 they will be prompted to 'Add' the pass.

If a user's passbook already contains a pass of `passTypeIdentifier` pass.com.example with `serialNumber` 1234 *and* the content of the new pass is different to the pass they have installed, they will be prompted to 'Update' the pass.

If the pass is already installed but the data has not changed then the right button will be disabled with a message ('Added').

To see an example with a live pass, you can try downloading this [pass](https://pass.is/krERrj).  You will first be prompted to 'Add' the pass to your Passbook.

[image]

On the back of the pass is a link you can use to update the content.

[image]

If you click that, and change the content and select the 'Download' option, you will be presented with the 'Update' option.

[image]
[image]

If you click again but this time do not change any values and select 'Download' then you get the disabled 'Added' button.

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the co-founder of [PassKit](http://passkit.com), the service that created this pass.